Is it possible to do prefix delegation per shared-network using ISC DHCP?
I would like to use ISC DHCP to provide prefix delegation per RFC 3633 for a small ISP's customer network. While reading through ISC's documentation for dhcpd.conf(https://kb.isc.org/v1/docs/isc-dhcp-44-manual-pages-dhcpdconf), I found this bit of text under prefix6: "This statement is currently global but it should have a shared-network scope." This makes it sound as if I can only have one prefix6 statement for my dhcpd.conf when I would rather have separate prefix statements for each shared network.
Is my understanding correct, or is there a way to have per shared-network or subnet prefix6 statements?
OS: Rocky 8
DHCP: 4.3.6 as included in the OS repos
